# How do I select from a nested table column in Oracle using go?

Tags: oracle, go

I am using go1.10.1 and querying Oracle 11.2.0.4. My local Oracle client is a 12.2 instant client. The go Oracle driver is goracle 2.5.4.

I am querying a table with a nested table (id column) that I need to retrieve as a list or some other iterable object. The nested table is simply a table of numbers.

```
CREATE TYPE id_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE TABLE account
    (account_name VARCHAR2(1024), 
    id id_type)
    NESTED TABLE id STORE AS id_tab;
```

Can I use a native go type to retrieve the nested table or do I need to use a type in the goracle driver?

Can I use the standard `database/sql` package or do I need something additional like `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx`?